# Free antivirus that is controllable by user (can be stopped/exited etc.)

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus

There is an ongoing trend of software, especially antivirus, to be less and less controllable by user, probably supposing that the users' intelligence is lower than that of the software. For example, some 10 years ago (approx.) AVG Free allowed the user to switch off the resident feature and use it just for scanning, or to exit it completely. Later on, it was impossible. If you wanted to stop the protection (= overhead of scanning & updates) for particular moment, you had to uninstall it!

#### Does there exist any free antivirus software that is controllable by user? I'm using Windows XP.

I have tried AVG Free and Avast several years ago (situation might have changed since, though its unlikely) and was dissapointed in such a way that I completely refrained from using antivirus.

Comment: You can disable real-time protection with [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/security-essentials).  *Why* exactly you'd want to do that, however, is well beyond me.  And *that* is why I'm voting to close this as not constructive.

Comment: @Breakthrough, "Not constructive" means that the question doesn't lead to an answer, not that it is not useful to you! BTW, it is mentioned in the question. Anyway I guess it is quite obvious.

Comment: -1, question does not show research effort. Which antivirus solutions have you tried, even? Based on the answers, I guess none. Otherwise, please expand your question and show which antivirus solutions *don't* fit your criteria.

Comment: @slhck, from my question it is apparent I tried AVG free, but OK, I have updated my question. I have tried at least those two some year ago and was dissapointed. Now I just asked someone who knows to save time - what's wrong with that? Isn't this website for this purpose? I'm quite surprised by the frequency of adverse tone here...

Comment: The more research you do yourself, the better answers you get. If you haven't even tried to solve the problem yourself, that's just a bit "lazy" (forgive the word). There's nothing adverse other than what [ask] and the hover text on the downvote button says.

Comment: @slhck - in this case, lazy means effective. Why would I try to install something only to realize that the software doesn't allow that, when someone else knows this immediatelly? Think about it - that's a nonsense! It is not good to be lazy when you need to put necessary information to question, narrow the code down to specific case etc., but here your critics really doesn't make sense - the question is clear enough. I'm SO user for some time so I understand this critics and when it makes sense. But please refrain from template thinking, be more flexible and kind to users.

Comment: I'm always kind and trying to be helpful – I have never personally attacked you, have I? My main concern is that this question is spiraling into polling for an endless list of (partly subjective) answers, all of which you could have easily found for yourself. This is not the kind of question we really encourage. Yes, I know it's easy to just ask for a certain feature set and let the community come up with a list of answers, but it's just not something we encourage, that's all. I hope you understand that.

Comment: You can also see the panda AV it is good featured AV. However I didn't use it ever but my friend is using it regularly and reports thayt it is good. I AM ON MOBILE so its hard to put the link there just search on Google and you will get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest MalwareBytes 
http://www.malwarebytes.org/ for the features your requesting.

In general I suggest Microsofts Security Essentials: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/security-essentials

Whatever the features your looking for MSE is pretty much the best bet out there.

Comment: Thanks Justin. What is MSE for? Is it antivirus?

Comment: Sorry MSE = Microsoft Security Essentials (yes antivirus and more) I would say that it is currently the best full solution to malware protection on windows. However it does not give you as much control as MalwareByte (which I think matches your original requirements better)

Comment: Many thanks Justin. It is *essential* :-) for me that the process can be quitted/exitted by user. Does MSE allow that? If not, then actually the other solution would be better for me.

Comment: I would say that Yes MSE allows that but if you want to be really sure go with MalwareBytes, its default mode is to only run if you request a scan. MalwareBytes is also pretty good.

Comment: BTW, malwarebytes seems to be shareware. Is there any limitation if I don't pay? Is it annoying with ads or request to register it?

Comment: I have never had a problem with it. I oversee a number of computers in my lab and we use the free version. It works wonderfully. But that question is rather qualitative, you will have to try it out for yourself.

Comment: I have now sucessfully used Malwarebytes Anti-Malware to remove Live Security Platinum virus, using [this instruction](http://www.myantispyware.com/2012/06/01/how-to-remove-live-security-platinum-virus/).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to try [Avira](http://www.avira.com/en/index), it works in Windows XP and 7, and can be disable by user, and in options you can disable totally the resident scan.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, I'd recommend [Comodo](http://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/free-internet-security.php?key5sk1=f716fb6b18efb06392ad18ae20d30416e88259f6&key5sk2=2128&key5sk3=1337786867000&key5sk4=2720&key5sk5=1337786868000&key5sk6=2720&key5sk7=1337786873000&key6sk1=&key6sk2=CH190108446&key6sk3=8&key6sk4=en-us&key6sk5=BE&key6sk6=0&key6sk7=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.comodo.com%252F&key6sk8=112202&key6sk9=12801024&key6sk10=true&key6sk11=95994ea4199587d7779e6c3c7a031fd27b7e0222&key7sk1=2&key7sk2=19&key1sk1=dt&key1sk2=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.comodo.com%252F). There's a free version available. It's completely configurable, and lets you turn features on and off. It's also the only antivirus I've used that never let a virus slip through (or at least, that I know of).

Answer (score 1):

If all you're wanting to do is scan for threats, then why bother installing anything at all? Just run Comodo portable scanner, or similar. A quick google search for "portable antivirus windows XP" will pop-up quite a few decent results in the top 10.

Comodo Scanner: http://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/cloud-scanner.php